# What is the most efficient way to get borders in Google Apps Script

Tags: performance, google-apps-script, border, google-sheets-api

What is the best way to get border details in Google Apps Script?

I cannot see anything with borders in the documentation for GAS, so I have had to resort to getting borders through the Spreadsheet API.

This works ok, other than when the number of borders gets large where it will take a long time to return, or not return at all.

Is there a better way to do this?

```
var fieldsBorders = 'sheets(data(rowData/values/userEnteredFormat/borders))';

var currSsId = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getId();
var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var name = activeSheet.getName();

var data = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(currSsId, {
    ranges: name,
    fields: fieldsBorders
});
```

Comment: I think that using Sheets API for retrieving the borders in the Spreadsheet is suitable. So can I ask you about the situation of ``when the number of borders gets large where it will take a long time to return, or not return at all.``?

Comment: So as an example I set all cells in a default 26 x 1000 spreadsheet and tried to get the borders using the above call, it timed out saying too much data.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In my environment, when I set the borders for 26 x 1000 cells and run your script, the process time was about 50 s. So can you provide the detail flow for replicating your situation? I would like to confirm it and think of your solution or workaround.

Comment: perhaps it was a bigger sheet it was on, either way 50s is a long time to get the borders.  The other calls to GAS take a very small amount of time to complete.  Can you confirm this is the only way to get borders?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I proposed a workaround as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- You want to reduce the process cost for retrieving the borders from a sheet in Spreadsheet.
- When I set the borders for 26 x 1000 cells and run your script, the process time was about 50 s in my environment.

  - For this situation, you want to reduce the cost more.
  - Your reply comment is `perhaps it was a bigger sheet it was on, either way 50s is a long time to get the borders. The other calls to GAS take a very small amount of time to complete. Can you confirm this is the only way to get borders?`

If my understanding is correct, how about this workaround? In this workaround, I request directly to the endpoint of Sheets API for retrieving the borders.

### Workaround:

#### Sample situation

In this sample script, as a sample situation, I supposes the default sheet which has 26 columns x 1000 rows, and the borders are set to all cells.

#### Sample script 1:

In this sample script, the borders are retrieved by one API call.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var fileId = ss.getId();
var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var fields = "sheets/data/rowData/values/userEnteredFormat/borders";
var params = {
    method: "get",
    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " +  token},
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
};
var range = sheetName + "!A1:Z1000";
var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + fileId + "?ranges=" + encodeURIComponent(range) + "&fields=" + encodeURIComponent(fields); 
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
var result = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
```

Result:

- When the sample script 1 was used, the average process time was 2.2 seconds.

  - Although I'm not sure about the internal process of Sheets API of Advanced Google Service, it was found that when it directly requests to the endpoint, the process cost can be reduced.

#### Sample script 2:

In this sample script, the borders are retrieved with the asynchronous process by several API calls.

```
var sep = 500; // Rows retrieving by 1 request.
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var fileId = ss.getId();
var sheetName = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
var fields = "sheets/data/rowData/values/userEnteredFormat/borders";
var requests = [];
var maxRows = 1000;
var row = 1;
for (var i = 0; i < maxRows / sep; i++) {
  var range = sheetName + "!A" + row + ":Z" + (row + sep - 1);
  requests.push({
    method: "get",
    url: "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + fileId + "?ranges=" + encodeURIComponent(range) + "&fields=" + encodeURIComponent(fields),
    headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " +  token},
  });
  row += sep;
}
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetchAll(requests);
var result = response.reduce(function(ar, e) {
  var obj = JSON.parse(e.getContentText());
  Array.prototype.push.apply(ar.sheets[0].data[0].rowData, obj.sheets[0].data[0].rowData);
  return ar;
}, {sheets: [{data: [{rowData: []}]}]});
```

Result:

When the sample script 2 was used, the following results were obtained.

- When `sep` is 500 (in this case, 2 API calls are run.), the average process time was 1.9 seconds.
- When `sep` is 200 (in this case, 5 API calls are run.), the average process time was 1.3 seconds.

But if the number of requests in one run are increased, the error related to the over of quotas occurs. Please be careaful this.

### Note:

- **This is a simple sample for testing above situation. So I think that above script cannot be used for all situations. If you use above sample script, please modify it for your situation.**

### References:

- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)
- [Benchmark: fetchAll method in UrlFetch service for Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c0f383034045ab63c19604139ecb0728)

Comment: That’s fantastic thanks so much for your detailed response. Unfortunately I am on annual leave now for the next week, so I may not be unable to test this properly until I am back, it certainly looks exactly what I am looking for though.  I would be thrilled if it can get down to 2 seconds from 50 calling it directly. I am really hoping it can manage a lot more cells as well, I sometimes have to deal with 500,000 cells of data so even if this takes 10 seconds or so and doesn’t time out that would be fantastic.

Comment: @user3284707 Thank you for replying. Although I have never confirmed about 500,000 cells yet, I think that the direction for reducing the cost is the same. As an important point, when you test the script, if the number of requests in one run are increased, the error related to the over of quotas occurs. Please be careful this.