# How to efficiently copy borders (with formatting and values) between Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, spreadsheet

**Question Description**:

In Google Apps Script, when we need to copy a range from one sheet to another within the same spreadsheet, we can use the `copyTo` method. However, when attempting to copy a range to a sheet in a different spreadsheet, there's no direct method available, even when utilizing the Sheets API.

A previous answer provided a workaround for copying most formatting properties except borders from one spreadsheet to another. It involves retrieving formatting information and applying it to the target range. Unfortunately, this method does not handle border formatting.

To copy an entire sheet to another spreadsheet and maintain borders, the `copyTo` method can be used for the entire sheet, followed by overwriting values. However, this approach is impractical if other content on the destination sheet should remain unchanged.

An efficient solution to handle border formatting is provided in a response by Tanaike on Stack Overflow. By utilizing the Sheets API, it's possible to retrieve border formatting details. However, applying these formatting details to a range in another spreadsheet remains a challenge.

I'm seeking guidance on the most efficient way to apply border formatting retrieved using the Sheets API to a range in another spreadsheet. I am open to alternative approaches.

**Related Links**:

- [copyTo method - Google Apps Script Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination)
- [Copy value and format from a sheet to a new Google Spreadsheet document?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25106580/copy-value-and-format-from-a-sheet-to-a-new-google-spreadsheet-document)
- [Tanaike's response on retrieving border formatting details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055708/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-borders-in-google-apps-script)

Comment: First, I deeply apologize that my answer was not useful for your situation. And, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: I am sorry for late reply, and I also apologize for my poor English skill. I want to copy borders of a range (say "B2:D3") of a sheet from a Google spreadsheet to a range (say "E4:G5") of a sheet in 'different' Spreadsheet. All I would like to achieve through Sheets API. I can retrieve the border details using your answer. However I am not able to prepare the object to send for border update, as mentioned in this documentation https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. From your reply, do you want to copy only the borders? Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your actual expected result.

Comment: Yes, let us go for it. However I would like to write a function which can copy whatever we specify in arguments, e.g. function copyPaste_usingSheetsAPI(object){}, object can have keys like copyBorders, copyValues, copyBacakground, copyTextFormats etc.  If one or more keys present in the object then function will do that.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to support you. But, I have to apologize for my poor English skill, again. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot still understand your question. But I would like to try to understand it. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and interest. I want to copy and paste only borders. Please check the function tryBordersCopyPaste() in my answer, to understand what I want to do.  I have tried, but if you can modify my answer or give some another answer which might make it time and load efficient, then I will be happy.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I saw your answer. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Comment: Thank you for your interest. As I mentioned in my answer's remark, the request object for 'updateBorders' includes an object for each individual cell in the range. If there are 1000 rows and 26 columns, there are 26000 objects, but if we can identify the cells having same 'innerHorizontal' and/or 'innerVertical' borders, then we can combine objects of those cells into one object. In copyPasteBordersOnly() func, I have commented a part, using some technique one may combine those objects into one object. This can decrease the payload size (ideal 2 MB size). I apologize for my poor English skill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You want to copy borders from a range of a sheet of some spreadsheet to the range of a sheet of another spreadsheet

  - I used the script given by Tanaike to get source borders using Sheets API
  - I have shared two spreadsheets to try the code
  - `I have verified it for a range of 1000 rows and 26 columns`

#### Script 1:

This is made using Tanaike's answer

```
function getBordersEfficiently_usingSheetsAPI_thanksTo_Tanaike(spreadsheetId, sheetName, rangeA1){

  // Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055708/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-borders-in-google-apps-script

  // link to open: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c1WLAZahyjfXoM3MQKz4S5HgDlmgLEHlvrC4Rk09i28/
  // var spreadsheetId = "1c1WLAZahyjfXoM3MQKz4S5HgDlmgLEHlvrC4Rk09i28"; 
  // var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Name of the source sheet
  // var rangeA1 = "A1:E10"; 

  var token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  var fields = "sheets/data/rowData/values/userEnteredFormat/borders";
  var params = {
      method: "get",
      headers: {Authorization: "Bearer " +  token},
      muteHttpExceptions: true,
  };
  // var rangeA1WithSheetName = sheetName + "!A1:Z1000";
  var rangeA1WithSheetName = sheetName + "!" + rangeA1;
  var url = "https://sheets.googleapis.com/v4/spreadsheets/" + spreadsheetId + "?ranges=" + encodeURIComponent(rangeA1WithSheetName) + "&fields=" + encodeURIComponent(fields); 
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  var result = JSON.parse(res.getContentText());
  // Logger.log("result = %s", result);
  return result;      
  
};
```

##### Result:

- Script 1 is time efficient

sample response:

```
result = {sheets=[{data=[{rowData=[{values=[{userEnteredFormat={borders={left={colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, style=SOLID_MEDIUM, color={}, width=2.0}, top={colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, style=SOLID_MEDIUM, color={}, width=2.0}, bottom={color={}, style=SOLID, colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, width=1.0}, right={color={}, width=1.0, style=SOLID, colorStyle={rgbColor={}}}}}}, {userEnteredFormat={borders={bottom={colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, style=SOLID, width=1.0, color={}}, left={width=1.0, style=SOLID, color={}, colorStyle={rgbColor={}}}, right={color={}, width=2.0, colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, style=SOLID_MEDIUM}, top={width=2.0, style=SOLID_MEDIUM, color={}, colorStyle={rgbColor={}}}}}}]}, {values=[{userEnteredFormat={borders={top={style=SOLID, colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, color={}, width=1.0}, bottom={colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, width=2.0, color={}, style=SOLID_MEDIUM}, right={style=SOLID, color={}, colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, width=1.0}, left={width=2.0, color={}, style=SOLID_MEDIUM, colorStyle={rgbColor={}}}}}}, {userEnteredFormat={borders={bottom={colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, style=SOLID_MEDIUM, width=2.0, color={}}, right={style=SOLID_MEDIUM, width=2.0, colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, color={}}, left={color={}, style=SOLID, width=1.0, colorStyle={rgbColor={}}}, top={colorStyle={rgbColor={}}, style=SOLID, color={}, width=1.0}}}}]}]}]}]}
```

#### Script 2:

In this sample script, the borders are retrieved using above script 1, then the received object is processed to convert into another object of 'updateBorders' method.

```
function copyPasteBordersOnly(source_spreadsheetId, source_sheetName, source_RangeA1, desination_spreadsheetId, desination_sheetName, desination_cellA1){

  const bordersObj = getBordersEfficiently_usingSheetsAPI_thanksTo_Tanaike(source_spreadsheetId, source_sheetName, source_RangeA1);
  Logger.log("bordersObj = %s", bordersObj);
  var source_Range = SpreadsheetApp.openById(source_spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(source_sheetName).getRange(source_RangeA1);

  const numRows_source_Range = source_Range.getNumRows();
  const numCols_source_Range = source_Range.getNumColumns();

  // If the range is out of bound, doesn't exist in the sheet then the received reponse is
  // bordersObj = {error={message=Range ('Sheet1'!AA89:AB92) exceeds grid limits. Max rows: 1000, max columns: 26, status=INVALID_ARGUMENT, code=400.0}}
  if("error" in bordersObj){
    return Logger.log("error message = %s", bordersObj.error.message);
  }

  const rowData_ofBorders = bordersObj.sheets[0].data[0].rowData;
  Logger.log("rowData_ofBorders = %s", rowData_ofBorders);

  if(rowData_ofBorders == null){
    return Logger.log("There are no borders in the source range");
  }

  const noOfRows_inReceivedObj = rowData_ofBorders.length;
  // These might be different in some cells have no borders in your source range
  Logger.log("noOfRows in received obj = %s, and numRows_source_Range = %s", noOfRows_inReceivedObj, numRows_source_Range);
  

  var updateBorders_Objs_2DArr = [];

  rowData_ofBorders.forEach((r, i) => {
    const values_arr = r.values;
    // Logger.log("values_arr = %s", values_arr);
    
    updateBorders_Objs_2DArr.push([]);
    if(values_arr == null){
        // Object is empty, means no borders in the first row of source range
        // we have to add blank object for each cell in this row
        updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[i].push(...Array(numCols_source_Range).fill({}));
    }else{
      // No. of columns in received object depends on the columns (from last) in source range having borders
      // Logger.log("This is no of columns in received object, values_arr.length = %s", values_arr.length);
      values_arr.forEach((r2, j) => {
        if(Object.keys(r2).length === 0){
          // Object is empty, means no borders
          updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[i].push({});
        }else{
          const userEntered_obj = r2.userEnteredFormat;
          // Logger.log("i = %s, j = %s, userEntered_obj = %s",i, j, userEntered_obj);
          const keys_userEntered_obj = Object.keys(userEntered_obj);
          // Logger.log("keys_userEntered_obj = %s", keys_userEntered_obj);
          keys_userEntered_obj.forEach(key =>{
            const borderObj_OfACell = {};
            const val_userEntered_obj = userEntered_obj[key];
            // Logger.log("val_userEntered_obj = %s", val_userEntered_obj);
            // ["top", "bottom", "left", "right"].forEach(side => {
            Object.keys(val_userEntered_obj).sort((a, b)=> a-b).forEach(side => {
              const thisSideProperties = val_userEntered_obj[side];
              // Logger.log("side = %s, thisSideProperties = %s", side, thisSideProperties);
              borderObj_OfACell[side] = {
                "width": thisSideProperties.width,
                "style": thisSideProperties.style,
                "color": ["red", "green", "blue"].reduce((clrObj, clr) => {
                  clrObj[clr] = clr in thisSideProperties.color ? thisSideProperties.color[clr] : 0.0;
                  return clrObj;
                  }, {}),
              }
            }); 
            // Logger.log("borderObj_OfACell = %s", borderObj_OfACell);
            updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[i].push(borderObj_OfACell);
          });
        }
      });
      // If the borders are not applied to all columns, or 
      // there are some cells in row (at the end of the row) which do not have any borders
      const numCols_InThisRow_OfReceivedObj = updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[i].length;
      // Logger.log("numCols_InThisRow_OfReceivedObj = %s", numCols_InThisRow_OfReceivedObj);
      if(updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[i].length < numCols_source_Range){
        // lets add extra blank objects
        updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[i].push(...Array(numCols_source_Range - numCols_InThisRow_OfReceivedObj).fill({}));
      }
    }
  })
  // Logger.log("updateBorders_Objs_2DArr = %s", updateBorders_Objs_2DArr);

  // Logger.log("numRows in received obj = %s", updateBorders_Objs_2DArr.length);
  // updateBorders_Objs_2DArr.forEach((r, i) => Logger.log("The length of '%s'th row = %s", i, r.length));
  // Logger.log("numCols in received obj = %s", updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[0].length);


  // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // // I can't do the following
  // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
  // // I was trying to do this, to decrease the size of the object to send
  // // If we can idenify the ranges having same innerHorizontal and innerVertical ranges
  // // then we can club those objects into one
  // const rowWiseGroup_sameFormatting = [];
  // const colWiseGroup_sameFormatting = [];

  // // Now let us verify, if same border is there for rows
  // for(var i = 0; i < updateBorders_Objs_2DArr.length; i++){
  //   // jo ek row na badha cell ma sarakhi borders hoy to check karie
  //   for(var j = 0; j < updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[i].length - 1; j++){
  //     const aCellStr = JSON.stringify(updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[i][j]);
  //     const nextCell_InRow_String = JSON.stringify(updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[i][j+1]);
  //     // Logger.log("aCellStr===nextCell_InRow_String = %s", aCellStr===nextCell_InRow_String);
  //     if(aCellStr===nextCell_InRow_String){
  //       Logger.log(`For i = ${i}, j = ${j}, aCellStr===nextCell_InRow_String`);
  //       rowWiseGroup_sameFormatting.push([i, j]);
  //     }
  //     const belowCell_InCol_String = i < updateBorders_Objs_2DArr.length - 1 ? JSON.stringify(updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[i+1][j]) : null;
  //     if(belowCell_InCol_String){
  //       if(aCellStr===belowCell_InCol_String){
  //         Logger.log(`For i = ${i}, j = ${j}, (aCellStr===belowCell_InCol_String`);
  //         colWiseGroup_sameFormatting.push([i, j]);
  //       }
  //     }
  //     Logger.log(`For i = ${i}, j = ${j}`);
  //     Logger.log("aCellStr = %s", aCellStr);
  //     Logger.log("nextCell_InRow_String = %s", nextCell_InRow_String);
  //     Logger.log("belowCell_InCol_String = %s", belowCell_InCol_String);
  //   }
  // }

  // Logger.log("rowWiseGroup_sameFormatting = %s", rowWiseGroup_sameFormatting);
  // Logger.log("colWiseGroup_sameFormatting = %s", colWiseGroup_sameFormatting);
  // /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

  const desination_sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(desination_spreadsheetId).getSheetByName(desination_sheetName);
  const desination_cell = desination_sheet.getRange(desination_cellA1);
  const destination_startRowIndex = desination_cell.getRow() - 1;
  const destination_startColumnIndex = desination_cell.getColumn() - 1;

  Logger.log("destination_startRowIndex = %s, destination_startColumnIndex = %s", destination_startRowIndex, destination_startColumnIndex);
  const desination_sheetId = desination_sheet.getSheetId();

  updateBorders_Objs_2DArr = updateBorders_Objs_2DArr.map((r, i) => {
    return r.map((obj, j) => {
      const anObj = {};
      
      anObj["updateBorders"] = {
        "range":{
          "sheetId": desination_sheetId,
          "startRowIndex": destination_startRowIndex + i,
          "endRowIndex": destination_startRowIndex + i + 1,
          "startColumnIndex": destination_startColumnIndex + j,
          "endColumnIndex": destination_startColumnIndex + j + 1,
        },
      };
      // left, right, bottom, top borders to add here
      Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => anObj["updateBorders"][key] = obj[key]);
      return anObj;
    });
  });

  // Here we may convert it into a 1D Array, however 2D Array also works fine

  // First to reset the borders, we have to set borders to none
  // so let us add first request object to reset borders
  const requestObj_toResetBorders =
    {
      updateBorders: {
        range: {
          sheetId: desination_sheetId,
          startRowIndex: destination_startRowIndex,
          endRowIndex: destination_startRowIndex + numRows_source_Range, // End row is exclusive, so add 1
          startColumnIndex: destination_startColumnIndex,
          endColumnIndex: destination_startColumnIndex + numCols_source_Range, // End column is exclusive, so add 1
        },
        top: {
          style: "none",
          width: 0.0,
          color: {
            red: 0.0, // Set red to 0 (assuming blue border as per your example)
            green: 0.0, // Set green to 0 (assuming blue border)
            blue: 0.0, // Set blue to desired color value
          },
        },
        bottom: {
          style: "none",
          width: 0.0,
          color: {
            red: 0.0, // Set red to 0 (assuming blue border as per your example)
            green: 0.0, // Set green to 0 (assuming blue border)
            blue: 0.0, // Set blue to desired color value
          },
        },
        left: {
          style: "none",
          width: 0.0,
          color: {
            red: 0.0, // Set red to 0 (assuming blue border as per your example)
            green: 0.0, // Set green to 0 (assuming blue border)
            blue: 0.0, // Set blue to desired color value
          },
        },
        right: {
          style: "none",
          width: 0.0,
          color: {
            red: 0.0, // Set red to 0 (assuming blue border as per your example)
            green: 0.0, // Set green to 0 (assuming blue border)
            blue: 0.0, // Set blue to desired color value
          },
        },
        innerHorizontal: {
          style: "none",
          width: 0.0,
          color: {
            red: 0.0, // Set red to 0 (assuming blue border as per your example)
            green: 0.0, // Set green to 0 (assuming blue border)
            blue: 0.0, // Set blue to desired color value
          },
        },
        innerVertical: {
          style: "none",
          width: 0.0,
          color: {
            red: 0.0, // Set red to 0 (assuming blue border as per your example)
            green: 0.0, // Set green to 0 (assuming blue border)
            blue: 0.0, // Set blue to desired color value
          },
        },
      },
    };
  
  updateBorders_Objs_2DArr.unshift(requestObj_toResetBorders);

  // Logger.log("Last, updateBorders_Objs_2DArr = %s", updateBorders_Objs_2DArr);
  // Logger.log("Last, updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[0][0] = %s", updateBorders_Objs_2DArr[0][0]);

  const finalRequestJsonObj = {
    "requests": updateBorders_Objs_2DArr
  }

  // console.log("finalRequestJsonObj = ");
  // console.log(finalRequestJsonObj);
  // Logger.log(JSON.stringify(finalRequestJsonObj, null, 2)); // logs properly

  // Docs.Documents.batchUpdate(requests, spreadsheetId);
  const response = Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(finalRequestJsonObj, desination_spreadsheetId);
  Logger.log(response);
  return response;
}
```

#### Script 3:

Sample use case:

```
function tryBordersCopyPaste(){
  // Source for Batch Update shared with everyone,  all have access to this spreadsheet
  // link to open: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1c1WLAZahyjfXoM3MQKz4S5HgDlmgLEHlvrC4Rk09i28/
  var source_spreadsheetId = "1c1WLAZahyjfXoM3MQKz4S5HgDlmgLEHlvrC4Rk09i28"; 
  var source_sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Name of the source sheet
  var source_RangeA1 = "B3:D6";
  // var source_RangeA1 = "F3:I7";
  // var source_RangeA1 = "G3:I7";
  // var source_RangeA1 = "A1:F10"; 
  // var source_RangeA1 = "A1:Z1000"; 

  // Destination for Batch Update shared with everyone, all can access this spreadsheet
  // link of destination sheet : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19Z0urdlXd3AM6Xhk1JbIxPHRfl0fh2UA4ArJ-aP8X9E/
  var desination_spreadsheetId = "19Z0urdlXd3AM6Xhk1JbIxPHRfl0fh2UA4ArJ-aP8X9E"; 
  // Name of the destination sheet
  var desination_sheetName = "Sheet1"; 
  // first cell (left-top) of the destination range, numRows and numColumns should be as per the source range
  var desination_cellA1 = "A1"; 

  copyPasteBordersOnly(source_spreadsheetId, source_sheetName, source_RangeA1, desination_spreadsheetId, desination_sheetName, desination_cellA1);

}
```

##### Response:

```
response = {replies=[{}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}], spreadsheetId=19Z0urdlXd3AM6Xhk1JbIxPHRfl0fh2UA4ArJ-aP8X9E}
```

##### Note:

- **Script 2 is `not` time efficient, as I mentioned in the code, we shall decrease the size of request object (size of the payload). For that we have to identify the ranges having same innerHorizontal and innerVertical borders. Then we can combine the objects of all those cells into one object of the whole range. I will be glade if anyone is interested in it.**

##### Remark:

- subject to limit of quotas of Sheets API calls, it changes time to time.

### References:

- [What is the most efficient way to get borders in Google Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56055708/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-get-borders-in-google-apps-script/56068835#56068835)
- [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/samples/formatting)
- [fetchAll(requests)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchallrequests)
- [Benchmark: fetchAll method in UrlFetch service for Google Apps Script](https://gist.github.com/tanaikech/c0f383034045ab63c19604139ecb0728)